# Image in html page cannot be found by c# html parser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using itextsharp dll to print web page in PDF .  I have a `<img src="Images/flower.jpg" />` in my html file.  The button click event below will render PDF fine when I don't have the image.  With the image, I got this error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\Images\flower.jpg'

Here is my code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: I have a <img src="Images/flower.jpg" />

Comment: In your HTML you need to give an absolute path to the image since a relative path would mean relative to the current working directory which is the path which you see when the error pops up.

Comment: That works.  Thanks.  This would mean I have to update the path once it moves to production server.

Comment: Yes, see my answer for a potentially better alternative if you have access to the image url through code. Don't forget to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution should be to change:

```
<img src="Images/flower.jpg" />
```

to:

```
<img src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/Images/flower.jpg" />
```

Otherwise you can use `Server.MapPath("Images/flower.jpg")` to get the full URL by code. However that implies you having to know the relative path to the image (meaning access to the raw html) at compile-time, which makes your code less maintainable.